# ReactStrap: Unable to hide navbar item according to screen size

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am following the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) in order to show a `NavItem` only for screen widths larger than `sm`.
According to the documentation, I have to use this attribute:
[image]
I tried it here:

```
  <NavItem className=".d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none">
              <NavLink
                data-placement="bottom"
                target="_blank"
                title="Profile"
                onClick={() => {
                  props.history.push("/profile-page");
                }}
              >
                <i className="fa fa-bell " />
                <p className="d-lg-none">Notifications</p>
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
```

But, this seems to have no effect. The navBar item (Notification Bell Icon) still gets displayed for widths larger than `sm`:

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should use class names without dot `<NavItem className="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">`

Answer (score 0):

You should use class names without dot `<NavItem className="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">`